# How do I fix this "is a variable but is used like a type" error?

Tags: c#, string, variables, types

I need to use a `for` loop to check a list of names from my database and need to match with the first two strings of a list that I store on my local drive, but I get the following error:

> nameMatch is a variable but is used like a type

I don't know how to solve this.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```cs
public bool isLightOn(Person lstName, string nameMatch)
{
    if(nameMatch !=null)
    {
        var name = nameMatch.substring(0,2)
        var cService = new PersonService();
        var persons = cService.ListPersons();

        nameMatch = nameFound;

        foreach(nameMatch nm in persons)
        {
            nameMatch = nm;
            if(nm.LastName == name )
                //do something..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as the error says, in `foreach(nameMatch nm in persons)` you are using `nameMatch` like a type when it's a parameter name.  Also, you should tag this question with what language this is (appears to be C#).

Comment: Can you say a little about why you typed `foreach(nameMatch nm in persons)` and what you believed `nameMatch` meant in that context?  I am interested to know how people come to make these sorts of mistakes so that I can design better diagnostics; evidently the diagnostic message you received did not adequately explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is almost certainly this one:

```
foreach(nameMatch nm in persons)
```

Most likely that declares a variable `nm` of *type* `nameMatch`, to iterate over the objects in `persons`.

It's hard to be certain since your question doesn't actually specify a language but that'd be the first place I'd be looking.

You should figure out what type is returned by `cService.ListPersons()` (eg, a collection of strings) and use that (eg, string) as the type.

Or it may be that this is a weakly typed language (like Python or Javascript), where variables can old any type. In that case, you won't need a type at all.

Comment: sorry my fault this is in C#